# C++ exceptions in Android JNI code - again

Tags: android, c++, exception, java-native-interface, try-catch

**Note** *this issue is now resolved - see my answer below - and unless someone deletes this post, it will stay here only to document only my own stupidity, I guess... Still, all the steps and config to make C++ exceptions work in Android JNI code are correct below, so maybe it will help someone occasionally - Greg*

I'm reading all possible material on this matter and cannot make my C++ exceptions in a statically built native library work... Any idea what I'm missing?

Application.mk, as you can see below I tried both gnustl_static and stlport_static, nothing works. I even forced a rebuild of stlport_static...

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION= 4.9
APP_PLATFORM := android-10
#APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_STL := stlport_static
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti
# STLPORT_FORCE_REBUILD := true
ifeq ($(NDK_DEBUG),1)
    APP_OPTIM := debug
    APP_ABI := x86
else 
    APP_OPTIM := release
    APP_ABI := mips armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
endif
```

The code I'm trying:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Generic external error exception
struct ExternalException : public std::exception
{
public:
    explicit ExternalException(const std::string &what)
        : message(what) {}
    virtual ~ExternalException() throw() {}
    const char      *what() const throw() { return message.c_str(); }
protected:
    const std::string message;
};
```

then elsewhere:

```
try
{
    ret = SomeFunction();
}
catch (...)
{
    ret = -1;
}
```

I also tried above `catch (ExternalException& e) {...}`, also does not help.

SomeFunction() calls at a certain error condition:

```
throw ExternalException(what);
```

Then the app simply crashes. When I analyze stack trace, I see that the exception *Unwind*...() call does nothing and then it falls through to a terminate function.

I feel like banging my head against a wall... What's wrong here???

Just for a quick reference, here are my local compiler options:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wno-write-strings -gdwarf-2
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fvisibility=hidden
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fvisibility=hidden
```

**Update**

Here is part of the stack trace captured, this was with armeabi-v7a build on a Nexus 6P device. Previously I tested debug builds on x86 emulator, exactly the same problem. Will try to test with different C/CPP flags next, maybe there is a conflict there?

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'google/angler/angler:6.0.1/MMB29P/2473553:user/release-keys'
pid: 12307, tid: 12352, name: AsyncTask #4  >>> com.hyperionics.avar <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Stack frame     #00 pc 00042374  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
Stack frame     #01 pc 0003ff81  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
Stack frame     #02 pc 0001c73f  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
Stack frame     #03 pc 000198f1  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
Stack frame     #04 pc 000174b0  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
Stack frame     #05 pc 002ac143  /data/app/com.hyperionics.avar-1/lib/arm/libHyperionics_avar.so: Routine __gabixx::__default_terminate() at /tmp/ndk-user/tmp/build-stlport/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/src/terminate.cc:75
Stack frame     #06 pc 002ac14d  /data/app/com.hyperionics.avar-1/lib/arm/libHyperionics_avar.so: Routine __gabixx::__terminate(void (*)()) at /tmp/ndk-user/tmp/build-stlport/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/src/terminate.cc:84
Stack frame     #07 pc 002ac1a5  /data/app/com.hyperionics.avar-1/lib/arm/libHyperionics_avar.so: Routine std::terminate() at /tmp/ndk-user/tmp/build-stlport/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/src/terminate.cc:110
Stack frame     #08 pc 002ab80f  /data/app/com.hyperionics.avar-1/lib/arm/libHyperionics_avar.so: Routine __cxxabiv1::call_terminate(_Unwind_Control_Block*) at /tmp/ndk-user/tmp/build-stlport/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/src/helper_func_internal.cc:54
Stack frame     #09 pc 002ab21d  /data/app/com.hyperionics.avar-1/lib/arm/libHyperionics_avar.so: Routine throwException at /tmp/ndk-user/tmp/build-stlport/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/src/cxxabi.cc:271
Stack frame     #10 pc 002ab2e1  /data/app/com.hyperionics.avar-1/lib/arm/libHyperionics_avar.so: Routine __cxa_throw at /tmp/ndk-user/tmp/build-stlport/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gabi++/src/cxxabi.cc:335
Stack frame     #11 pc 00045e58  /data/app/com.hyperionics.avar-1/lib/arm/libHyperionics_avar.so: Routine IOError(std::string const&, std::string const&) at C:\android\TtsNativeLib/jni/mylib/error.h:128 (discriminator 4)
```

Greg

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your results. Are you sure that you don't throw any other exceptions, either explicitly or implictly? Does this happen for you on all CPU architectures? I built the library for `armeabi` and tested it on a Nexus 4. I also replaced `String` in your exception type with `std::string` since I wasn't what `String` is supposed to be.

Comment: @Michael, thank you for trying this! Sorry about String issue, it's just a typedef for std::string. I'll correct the code to in my post to make this less confusing. My yesterday testing was in x86 emulator, will try both debug and release builds on both x86 and arm to see if there is any difference.

Comment: @Michael - same problem on armeabi-v7a, Nexus 6P device, release build this time. Will add the captured stack trace to my question post. Could you send me or post your sample code and the exact flags, everything - for the sample that worked for you? Maybe my CFLAGS or CPPFLAGS conflict somehow...

Comment: Here are the relevant parts: http://pastebin.com/pgbyFVbD   What does `IOError` look like?

Comment: @Michael thank you! Indeed the simple example works, my big library no... Will rack my brain more, analyze the structure etc. The IOError() on my stack trace is just a one line inline function that calls: throw ExternalException(what); (originally it is a different exception class with a file name argument as well, simplified for this testing).

Comment: @Michael, found the solution, sorry for taking your time, and thank you very much for checking this out for me. Posted what was wrong as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies, all works right. It was my programming error, apparently working at the evenings I'm not in my best.

Briefly, what was the problem: in my call to the SomeFunction() I actually had parameters, and the exception was in creation of these parameters, not inside the function. Simply my 'try {' instruction had to be move up... It was like:

```
Ptr<OutPackedStream> pout = CreatePackedStream(fname.c_str());
try
{
    ret = SomeFunction(pout);
}
catch (...)
{
    ret = -1;
}
```

So obviously I couldn't catch an exception in CreatePackedStream(), because it was not inside try{}... What confused me though was that the stack trace was pointing at `ret = SomeFunction(pout)` line, only then went to `CreatePackedStream()`. Now looking at the code, and also my stack traces this is so obvious, sorry again for my clumsiness!

Greg